# How to move flash movie which embed in DIV with javascript?

Tags: javascript, flash, move

All:
I create a DIV in HTML and embed one flash in DIV. below is the HTML:

```
<head>
...
<script src="Scripts/swfobject_modified.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script src="Scripts/GHAnimateObjectMove.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<style type="text/css">
.GHLogoAniFlashDiv {
    margin: auto auto auto auto;
    height: 302px;
    width: auto;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.FlashID {
    margin: auto auto auto auto;
    height: 302px;
    width: 402px;
    left: auto;
    top: auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}  
</style>
</head>

<body>
<!-- align="center" align="absmiddle" align="center"  -->
<div id="GHLogoAniFlashDiv" > 
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="402" height="302"     class="FlashID" id="FlashID" title="GHLogoAniFlash">
<param name="movie" value="Animate/GHLogoAniFlash.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" />
<param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
<param name="SCALE" value="noscale" />
<embed src="Animate/GHLogoAniFlash.swf" quality="high" 
    width="402" height="302" name="movie"  
    play="true"
    loop="ture"
    quality="high"
    allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
    pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
</embed>
<!-- No IE -->
<!--[if !IE]> align="absmiddle"-->
<object data="Animate/GHLogoAniFlash.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="402" height="302" >
 <!--[end if]-->
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
  <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" />
  <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
  <param name="SCALE" value="noscale" />
  <!-- Version of Flash Player <6.0 -->
  <div>
    <h4>Need Latest Adobe Flash Player。</h4>
    <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img  src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash Player" width="112" height="33" /></a></p>
  </div>
  <!--[if !IE]>-->
  </object>
  <!--<![end if]-->
  </object>
  </div>
  ...
```

Then I use javascript in "GHAnimateObjectMove.js" to move the flash to one position of browser:

```
function SetGHLogoDivLocation()//Set Logo DIV location;
{
        var leftoffset=0;
    var rightoffset=0;
    LogoDivObj=document.getElementById("GHLogoAniFlashDiv");
    FlashObj=document.getElementById("FlashID");    
    try{
        findDimensions();
        leftoffset=parseInt(600);
        rightoffset=parseInt(300);
        LogoDivObj.style.postion="relative";
        if(LogoDivObj && FlashObj)
        {
            LogoDivObj.style.left=leftoffset+"px";
            LogoDivObj.style.top=rightoffset+"px";
            FlashObj.style.left=LogoDivObj.style.left;
            FlashObj.style.top=LogoDivObj.style.top;
        }
    }
    catch(err){
        window.alert(err.message);
    }
} 
...
window.onresize=function (){SetGHLogoDivLocation();};
window.onload=function () {SetGHLogoDivLocation()};
```

But It seem can't move flash to new position (600px,300px). It still stay at left of the page. Why? anyone know it?
I test on IE 9 win7. I debug in eclipse. I saw the LogoDivObj.style.left ,LogoDivObj.style.top,FlashObj.style.left and FlashObj.style.top already been changed. But why flash can't move to new position?